# NoMethodError in Products#index in delete method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I am getting NoMethodError for this line <%= link_to "Delete", delete_product_path(p), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %> or <%= link_to "Delete", delete_product_path(p), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>.. I used the resources for my routes..

Question: Why is that?

NOTE: I also tried <%= link_to 'Delete', delete_product_path(p) like the video said, it's not working on me

**View**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>MY STORE!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><align="center"> WELCOME TO MY STORE</h1>
    <%= link_to 'Add Product', new_product_path %>
    <table border = "1" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Image</td>

            <td>Size</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Created At</td>
            <td>Updated At</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
        <% @product.each do |p| %>

        <tr>
            <td><%= p.id %></td>
            <td><%= p.name %></td>

            <td><%= p.size %></td>
            <td><%= p.price %></td>
            <td><%= p.created_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %></td>
            <td><%= p.updated_at.strftime("%B, %d, %Y") %></td>
            <td>
            <%= link_to 'View', product_path(p) %>
            <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(p) %>
            <%= link_to 'Delete', delete_product_path(p), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Routes**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 resources :products
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

**Controller**

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @product = Product.all.order('created_at DESC')

  end
  def show
    @post = Product.find(params[:id])
  end
  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end
  def create
    @post = Product.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
    redirect_to (products_path)
    else
    redirect_to (new_product_path)
    end
  end
  def edit
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])

  end
  def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.update_attributes(post_params)
    redirect_to (products_path)
    else
    redirect_to (products_path)
    end
  end
  def delete
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  end
  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
    redirect_to(products_path)
```

end
      private
        def post_params
          params.require(:product).permit(:name, :size, :price)
        end

```
end
```

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', p, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

The route is

```
/products/:id
```

So the named path is not delete_product_path. It is the product path with the id and with the method delete to destroy it.

Remove the delete method from your controller and set your destroy method like this

```
  # DELETE /products/1
  # DELETE /products/1.json
  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

The method it looks for is destroy.  You never call ".destroy" which is the action that actually deletes the record.  What your method did was find it based on the id, so that is why it was showing.

Comment: It didnt, it just show the information of the product(like show method)

Comment: Your methods are a little off, I'll update my answer with the correct destroy method

Comment: I updated my destroy method, I just followed the instructions given by the video

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140144/discussion-between-angel-and-rockwell-rice).